# grade multiple responses from different users

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I want to grade/score the response of different users inputs. For this I have used `Multinomial navie bayes`. The below my code.

```
# use natural language toolkit
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import os
import json
import datetime
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()   
# 3 classes of training data
training_data = []
# capture unique stemmed words in the training corpus
class_words={}
corpus_words = {}
classes = list(set([a['class'] for a in training_data]))
for c in classes:
    class_words[c] = []

for data in training_data:
    # tokenize each sentence into words
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(data['sentence']):
        # ignore a few things
        if word not in ["?", "'s"]:
            # stem and lowercase each word
            stemmed_word = stemmer.stem(word.lower())
            if stemmed_word not in corpus_words:
                corpus_words[stemmed_word] = 1
            else:
                corpus_words[stemmed_word] += 1

            class_words[data['class']].extend([stemmed_word])

# we now have each word and the number of occurances of the word in our training corpus (the word's commonality)
print ("Corpus words and counts: %s" % corpus_words)
# also we have all words in each class
print ("Class words: %s" % class_words)
sentence="The biggest advantages to a JavaScript having a ability to support all modern browser and produce the same result."
def calculate_class_score(sentence, class_name):
    score = 0
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence):
        if word in class_words[class_name]:
            score += 1
    return score
for c in class_words.keys():
    print ("Class: %s  Score: %s" % (c, calculate_class_score(sentence, c)))
# calculate a score for a given class taking into account word commonality
def calculate_class_score_commonality(sentence, class_name):
    score = 0
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence):
        if word in class_words[class_name]:
            score += (1 / corpus_words[word])
    return score
# now we can find the class with the highest score
for c in class_words.keys():
    print ("Class: %s  Score: %s" % (c, calculate_class_score_commonality(sentence, c)))
def find_class(sentence):
    high_class = None
    high_score = 0
    for c in class_words.keys():
        score = calculate_class_score_commonality(sentence, c)
        if score > high_score:
            high_class = c
            high_score = score
    return high_class, high_score
```

**Note:** I haven't added any training data.

When I give the input as

```
find_class("the biggest advantages to a JavaScript having a ability to
 support all modern browser and produce the same result.JavaScript
 small bit of code you can test")
```

I'm getting the output as

```
('Advantages', 5.07037037037037)
```

But when I give the input as

```
find_class("JavaScript can be executed within the user's browser
without having to communicate with the server, saving on bandwidth")
```

I'm getting the response/output as

```
('Advantages', 2.0454545)
```

I'm building it for the JavaScript Interview/viva questions.
When a user type the same answer in the different way as I mentioned above I'm getting I'm getting different scores. I want the scores to be precise. How can I do it.

Comment: You didn't mention a lot of important points and people might not be interested in reading your code. Please mention what kind of features you are working with, and explain what the output means instead of saying "I'm getting the output as". Edit your question to help other users help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm building a javascript interview question model using that algorithm. I haven't mentioned the training data in the above question. I have given the advantages of JS (multiple answers) in the  `training_data.append `.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why should the score be same for the two input sentences? Maybe the second sentence matched lesser number of words in your training data (BTW that's not the correct term here). Still there is too much code, too little explanation.

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE read this before asking a question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. 
People are spending personal/work time to help find answer to your question. Why do you want to increase their task?

Comment: Are you trying to solve an interview question or are you building a reference answer?

Answer (score 1):

Multinomial Naive Bayes compares word occurrences. It does not take order into consideration since it considers every feature as independent of other. Thus, semantic similarity (different sentences, same meaning) is not always an easy problem to solve with Naive Bayes.

If in your case semantic similarity has some direct correlation to words present (to an extent that order can be ignored), then you can try following things:

1. Play around with data. See what results efforts like stopwords removal or using techniques like TF-IDF yield.
2. See if Word2Vec (or Doc2Vec) get you better results
3. Use more training data

These are very lazy suggestions that I can give without knowing much about how your data looks.

Answer (score 0):

Multinomial Naive Bayes will output different scores for different inputs. This is true for any classification algorithm actually.

The only way to get the same score for two different sentences is for the sentences to contain exactly the same words (in different order, or frequency)

See [the algorithm's definition](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html) for more detail.